# Data with hyphen copied from sql to excel is displaying incorrectly

Tags: microsoft-excel, export, contacts

Below is the data:

1)  +9180 33575586 - Copied shows correctly on excel
2) +9180-33575625 - Copied shows just -33566445 on excel.

On read tab looks like =9180-33575625.
Please advice this is creating me issues while exporting

Comment: I believe the cause is excel assumes + prefixed number with hyphen as formula.

Comment: Can someone help to overcome this issue?

Comment: Right click on the cell select "Format Cells...", in the "Number" tab select Category: to be "General" . Then try to copy to that cell.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Excel changes it from +9180-33575625 to -33566445 is because Excel reades the first + sign as a start of an equation. This can be avoided by adding a single quote at the start i.e. '+9180-33575625.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the format of the cell to Text.